# Web приложения для Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

У Chrome есть свой [Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore?hl=ru), в котором куча разных интересных вещей. От [Angry Birds](chrome.angrybirds.com) до сих пор не могу оторваться. Ни кому, случайно, не попадалась какая-либо информация на русском о том, как создавать такие приложения, опубликовывать и монетизировать?

Comment: Вся документация на английском есть на сайте Google: [Developer Docs][1]. На русском ни разу не встречалось. По сути эти приложения - это просто веб-страницы. А магазин торгует ссылками на страницы. 

[1]: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/chrome/apps/docs/index.html

Comment: Ну в принципе да, но вот посмотрел на <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl">TweetDeck</a> и захотелось тоже сделать что-то в это роде)

Answer (score 1):

[Офф статья на русском](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=ru)

[Неплохая статья на ibm developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-extendchrome/)

[Очень подробная статья](http://canonium.com/index.php/articles/briefly-about-building-a-chrome-extension)

[ha](http://habrahabr.ru/post/198652/)[br](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75639/)

Монетезировать либо через [in-app purchase](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) (на русском инструкций нету), либо добавляя рекламу